# Stylize element according to its index number

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I've been trying a few things but didn't find any that perfectly fits what I want to do.

The following snippet is the kind of things I'd like to achieve…

```css
ul {
  --liWidth: 10px;
}

ul li {
  margin-left: calc(var(--liWidth) * var(--n));
  font-size: calc(20px - 1px * var(--n));
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="--n: 1;">LI 1</li>
  <li style="--n: 2;">LI 2</li>
  <li style="--n: 3;">LI 3</li>
  <li style="--n: 4;">LI 4</li>
  <li style="--n: 5;">LI 5</li>
  <li style="--n: 6;">LI 6</li>
  <li style="--n: 7;">LI 7</li>
  <li style="--n: 8;">LI 8</li>
</ul>
```

… But without using my `n` CSS-var.
Why? I don't want to type it if using a hundred `li`s.

Is there anything like `margin-left: calc(var(--liWidth) * nth-of-type());` possible ?
If it's not, what is the easiest **without** using JavaScript ? (I already know how to do with it)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53611964/8620333

Comment: Hey @TemaniAfif, nice one. I'm gonna edit my question. The "stair" effect isn't necesarilly what I want (but it was the easiest to do). It could be a font increase, for example.

Comment: I don't think you can easily do such thing without nested element (anoher example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49977591/8620333) .. Your only easy way will be to use SASS/LESS to generate the code

Comment: @Paulie_D Where is the duplicate?… These are 2 questions on 2 different topics/methods: 1) Stylize by index 2) Allow additive properties ⋅⋅⋅ If you want me to change the visual "goal" so that they look more different, I can.

Comment: **Essentially** you are asking the same question which is why IMO it's a duplicate. The answer is still that this is *not possible* with CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D If by *the same question* you mean that I ask if it is possible, yes, that's true. But, as I said, the topics are different. I don't mean to be rude, but I don't think all the question with "Is is possible to … ?" are duplicates.

Comment: @Paulie_D Anyway, if you really want to keep one of my topics as a *duplicate*, you could at least put it on the other, as this one was the first one.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'd like some feedback here, some discussion. Something constructive, in fact. I feel like I'm left out without good reason.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm still waiting.

Comment: @Paulie_D As you seem to be active right now… Do you still don't want to answer here?

Comment: I have nothing more to add.

Comment: @Paulie_D That's a shame, I thought this place was meant to exchange.