# How to sequentually increase CSS value for Padding property for Hierarchy structure?

Tags: css, padding, hierarchy

I have hardcoded padding for each of the padding hierarchy level.

I need the solution for any of level without hardcoding padding for each level.

```
.jdm-nav li {
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
}

.jdm-nav li a {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.jdm-nav li li a {
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.jdm-nav li li li a {
    padding-left: 45px;
}

.jdm-nav li li li li a {
    padding-left: 60px;
}
```

**li li li li ... a**

Every next step could be increased by `15px.`

Full code example.
There is the mobile menu with ability to dropdown each item by click dropdown icon in the right item corner. If there are the items to expand.

```css
.jdm-nav {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.jdm-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.jdm-nav {
  list-style: none;
}

.jdm-nav li {
  list-style: none;
}

.jdm-nav ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.jdm-nav a {
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  color: rgb(76, 92, 104);
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: .5em 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(76, 92, 104, 0.1);
}

.jdm-nav li {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative !important;
}

.jdm-nav li a {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.jdm-nav li li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.jdm-nav li li li a {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.jdm-nav li li li li a {
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.jdm-nav li {
  position: relative;
}

.jdm-nav li>[data-jdm-sub-menu-switcher] {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(76, 92, 104, 0.1);
  position: relative;
}

.jdm-nav li {
  position: relative !important;
}

.jdm-nav li.menu-item-has-children>ul {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 150ms max-height ease-out;
}

.jdm-nav li.menu-item-has-children>ul[data-jdm-state="expanded"] {
  max-height: initial;
}

.jdm-nav li.menu-item-has-children> :first-child {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.jdm-nav li.menu-item-has-children>[data-jdm-sub-menu-switcher] {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.jdm-nav li.menu-item-has-children>ul {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

.jdm-nav li>[data-jdm-sub-menu-switcher]::after {
  position: absolute;
}

.jdm-nav li>[data-jdm-sub-menu-switcher]::after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  content: '';
  clip-path: url(#prefix-mobile-dropdown-clip-mask);
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: rgb(76, 92, 104);
  display: inline-flex;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(50%);
}

.jdm-nav li.menu-item-has-children {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100fr 15fr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prefix-mobile-menu" class="mobile-menu-area prefix-mobile-menu" data-prefix-status="collapsed">
  <nav id="mobile-menu" class="jdm-nav">
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu-overflow">
      <li id="menu-item-2420" class="menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="1">1</a>
        <button data-jdm-sub-menu-switcher=""></button>
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="" data-jdm-state="expanded">
          <li id="menu-item-2418" class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">1.1</a>
            <button data-jdm-sub-menu-switcher=""></button>
            <ul class="sub-menu" style="" data-jdm-state="expanded">
              <li id="menu-item-2434" class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="1.1">1.1.1</a>
                <button data-jdm-sub-menu-switcher=""></button>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-2435">
                    <a href="1.1.1.1">1.1.1.1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-2436"><a href="1.1.1.2">1.1.1.2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-2437"><a href="1.1.1.3/">1.1.1.3</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-1832"><a href="2/">2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
  <defs>
   <clipPath
     viewbox="0 0 448 512"
     transform="scale(0.00223, 0.00195)"
     clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"
     id="prefix-mobile-dropdown-clip-mask">
    <path fill="#000000"
      d="M441.9 167.3l-19.8-19.8c-4.7-4.7-12.3-4.7-17 0L224 328.2 42.9 147.5c-4.7-4.7-12.3-4.7-17 0L6.1 167.3c-4.7 4.7-4.7 12.3 0 17l209.4 209.4c4.7 4.7 12.3 4.7 17 0l209.4-209.4c4.7-4.7 4.7-12.3 0-17z"
      class=""></path>
   </clipPath>
  </defs>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML structure as well? Thanks.

Comment: Put the padding on the `li` and stretch the left of the `a` out by a large fixed amount, I guess. (This is only a guess at what you’re trying to achieve, it doesn’t literally increase the padding on each `a`. Adding that information to your question might help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Put the padding on the `li` and stretch the left of the `a` out by a large fixed amount.

Illustrated:

```css
body > ul {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-right: -1em;
  padding-left: 150px;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #cff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">nested</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">navigation</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:;">forever</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript:;">and</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;">ever</a>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </ul>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">foo</a>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;">bar</a>
    </ul>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">baz</a>
</ul>
```

(Notice how the clickable area of each link extends all the way to the left.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for solve your problem

```css
.jdm-nav li {
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
}

.jdm-nav li{
   font-size:1.2em;
   padding-left: 3em;
}
.jdm-nav li a {
    
    background-color:red;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="jdm-nav">
  <li>
    <a>Item1</a>
    <ul>
    <li>
      <a>Item2</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>Item3</a>
          
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -6):

use pseudo function of css to increase the padding of every children by 15px.

Comment: CSS doesn't have "pseudo functions". Can you post a link or reference to the CSS spec regarding what you're referring to?

Comment: @Dai a related question to understand why your code (deleted answer) isn't working: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49973885/8620333 .. you will also find and idea for an ul/li structure